# MAMP using CURL on localhost

Tags: curl, mamp, php-curl, mamp-pro

I am writing an API in php. So this involves two projects on my laptop. The api project and the project calling the api.

If I put the API project on the production server, it works, so I believe the problem to be something with my MAMP Pro installation.

phpinfo() says CURL support is enabled - Version 7.65.1
My firewall is disabled

This is my code calling the API with CURL

```
$url = "http://localhost:8888/MyAPI/api/?endpoint=endpoint1
// $url = "https://www.myliveserver.com/api/?endpoint=endpoint1 /* This works */

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->ApiKey ));

/* I have tried these options - still not working */
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8888);            
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch); /** This is the line it gets stuck at - no error, just waits .... */
$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curlErrorCode = curl_errno($ch);
$curlErrorMessage = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

How can I make CURL work on my localhost

Comment: assuming the API is consumed by a web appication (not a CLI script) have you correctly setup two virtual hosts on your MAMP installation? https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/General/

Comment: Thank you - I didn't have a separate host setup, but I have followed the instructions and done this. I am now getting an Internal Server error (500). So I will try and work this out. I am not sure which port I should be using for curl. I will try and find out.